# SharpSvn GetLog of deleted or renamed file / directory (SharpSvn Revision pegging)

Tags: c#, svn, version-control, configuration-management, sharpsvn

I am using SharpSvn client in one of my projects. I have a use-case where I need to display the history of a given file or folder. I am using the SharpSvn "GetLog" method for this. However, when I try to to list the revision log for each of the fetched items, I get an exception that the item (file or directory) was not found, the reason being the file or directory which was there in a earlier revision has been renamed or deleted and there fore does not exist on the server.

I read about pegging a revision and hence tried a CLI comand as below;

- svn log  svn://serverds/ModelManagement@215 > "D:\CMTestRun\SVNOutput.txt", which fetched all the log correctly (Pegging revision)

and a CLI command like;

- svn log -r 215 svn://markusdew764/ModelManagement > "D:\CMTestRun\SVNOutput.txt", just gave one entry.

I would like to know how I could achieve what the first CLI gave me using SharpSvn. I tried the GetLog with OperationalRevision but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any help on this would be much appreciated, as I couldn't find a solution or workaround for this yet.

Comment: did you find an answer?